# Search element in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone guide me how to find an element in an array?

I always get false for elements that exist.

Thank you.

```
arr = new Array;
arr.push({x: "a", y: 1});
arr.push({x: "b", y: 2});
arr.push({x: "c", y: 3});
​
elem = {x: "c", y: 3};
​
if (arr.includes(elem)){
    console.log('true');
} else {
    console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: JSON is "JavaScript Object Notation". JSON is a *string* representation of JavaScript Objects. There is no JSON here.

Comment: sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `{x: "c", y: 3}` object in `arr` and It will never be equal to any other object because `{} !== {}`.

**Remember:** Object are compared with *reference* but the primitives are checked by their *value*.

In your code you are checking an object reference with another reference, which is not equal so that's why it logs `false`.

If there are array of numbers then you should use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as:

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30];

if(arr.includes(20)) console.log("true");
else console.log("false");
```

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the element in the array

```js
const arr = new Array();
arr.push({ x: "a", y: 1 });
arr.push({ x: "b", y: 2 });
arr.push({ x: "c", y: 3 });

const elem = { x: "c", y: 3 };

if (arr.find((o) => o.x === elem.x && o.y === elem.y)) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and wonderful help, is there another simpler way to search or is this the only option?

Comment: This is the most direct and easiest method to check existence in an array of objects.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much, have a wonderful day, best regards.

Comment: A tangential note: `find` returns `undefined` or the element that is found. The found element is likely to be `truthy`, but generally you use `find` to get the element and could use `.some` to just test for existence. [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) vs. [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Hello @crashmstr
do you mean that **find** can return a false positive value? could you answer with an example how to use **some**?
Thanks.

Comment: I just replaced **find** with **some** and it worked, thanks

Comment: @NewDevUser Both are exactly same except the `return value`.

Comment: `[false, true].find(x => x === false)` will return `false`, so unless you test for `=== undefined`, you could mistake the return value. Yes, that is a contrived example, but if you want to test if any exist, `.some`, if you want the first object that matches, `.find`, if you want all objects that match, `.filter`.

Comment: @crashmstr That's correct. But what I meant was `find` will return the first element that satisfy the condition else return `false` and `some` will return Boolean value whether the element exist or not. In the example that you gave, `false` is a Boolean and also a value. In the case of `find` it will return the value i.e. `false` that satisfy the condition i.e. `x === false` and in the case of `some` it will return whether the `false` exist in array or not i.e. return `true` in this case. Hope I'm not wrong. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Happy to learn 

Comment: @HR01M8055 `.find` will return the found element or `undefined` (a falsy value, but not false). You can also contrive an example where it returns `undefined` when `undefined` is a value in the array (so there exists a value that matches the predicate and `.some` would return true but `.find` returns undefined). My point is that the choice is informative to the reader of the code as to what is wanted out of it: Do you want to check for any matching, get the first matching, get all matching, or check if all match? Use the tool that matches intent most closely.

Answer (score 1):

since you are working with a 2d array i believe your object will be allways same for X and Y , so i suggest you to make a function like that for further use in your code

```js
arr = new Array;
arr.push({x: "a", y: 1});
arr.push({x: "b", y: 2});
arr.push({x: "c", y: 3});

elem = {x: "c", y: 3};

console.log(findXY(arr,elem))

function findXY(arr,val){
  return arr.find(each=>{
    return each.x == val.x && each.y == val.y
  })
}
```